# Can we recruit more statisticians to participate in CV?

Tags: discussion

I think that if there is an awareness of the statisticians of the professional societies of the purpose and success of StackExchange CV many would want to help out.  In the ASA quantitative literacy has been our goal to improve.  Incoming ASA President Marie Davidian gave a presentation yesterday on a grant program she has to teach basic statistics for the aim of getting more American born students interested in pursuing a career in statistics or a related field.  There is a recognition of the ever-growing need for statistics to handle big data problems and the Obama administration commitment to find research in these quantitative areas.

The great thing that CV does is to get the experts to teach the novices some basic statistics in the context of problems they are working on.  The accumulation from many examples improves everyone's knowledge of good statistical practice including the experts'.  If the ASA leadership could see how effective we are and have some assurance that the final accepted answers are sound I am sure they would feel an obligation to participate or at least encourage others to do so.

Who should we approach (ASA president, Presidents Elect, Past Presidents, other society leaders)? Would there be any changes to our system that would increase the participation of ASA members?

Comment: +1 Many thanks for sharing these thoughts and opening this conversation, Michael.

Comment: +1 These are interesting questions, although I, being European, think that "ASA members" could be replaced by "statisticians" ;)

Comment: @MansT Thanks.  I focussed on ASA members because I am at the JSM right now and can talk to some of these people.  I did see all the presidents of ASA at the awards committee meeting.  Nancy Geller past president led the session.  Robert Rodriguez the current president was in attendence. President elect Marie Davidian was there and was the incoming President Elect Nat Schenker.  They all know me now and appreciate my contribution as chair on the Dixon Award committee.  So I think I can have an influence on them.  We live in a global electronic world.

Comment: Statistician everywhere can easily participate.  If European and Australian, Chinese, Japanese, Indian and statisticians from other countries in Europe, Asia, North and South America and Africa want to encourage colleagues to participate all the better!

Comment: I will be listening attently to the Presidential Address tonight and will inform you if I get into any discussions about StackExchange.  My guess is that most people I raise it to will have never heard of us.

Comment: There was an article about CV in AmStat News a few months ago, but most ASA members probably don't read their own newsletter.

Comment: @RobHyndman.  The fact that there was an article on StackExchange in AmStat News is interesting.  It would be good to follow this with editorial and commentary. Bob Rodriguez's address was about creating a big tent and having ASA have open arms to bring the data scientists into the fold and having initiatives and volunteering to make a difference and help people and society. So I think the ASA adminstration is going to be receptive to the concept and goals with stackexchange.  But I have always had an uneasiness about the system.

Comment: It has been my choice to participate. I like helping students and practitioners and I think that if this is done right it can meet everyone's goal to improve the practice of statistics.  Tonight I discussed the issue with a senior statistician who as I expected never heard of stackexchange,  We both agree about difficulties that would prevent any kind of ASA endorsement and without an endorsement I don't feel right about encouraging members to join.  I will list our reservations next.

Comment: PROBLEMS WE AGREE ON ARE  1) No real quality control or consistency and 2) most members are anonymous we don't know who they are or any serious credentials about statistical credentials or work experience.  Most bios I have seen just tell about their personal area of interest.

Comment: I have found that the only thing that holds things together is the dilligence and expertise of our two moderators.  I trust their judgement and appreciate their expertise. But the system needs structure and consistency it seems to me to lack.  A system that is based on reputation points assigned inconsistently by members who are novices and have no expertise to judge the correctness or incorrectness of answers.  I have seen correct answers that are counter to the OPs faulty intuition be downvoted and incorrect answers be upvoted because they agree with faulty intuition.

Comment: Moderators have too much power in some instances and not enough in others.  Quality should not depend on the vigilance of the moderator and how can we always trust that the moderator is knowledgeable and makes the right decision.

Comment: In addition to that voters are encouraged to downvote on the basis of style rather than substance.

Comment: A system like ours has good intentions and sometimes work.  But I am not sure the the benefits outweigh the negatives,

Comment: What you describe sounds an awful lot like the peer-review system, @Michael... ;)

Comment: @MichaelChernick As usual, with all the due respect, it seems like you are more worried about the credentials of the members than about the actual quality of the answers. Recall the famous saying "Change Yourself First to Change the World". The moderators repeatedly promote elaborated answers and "They lead by example".

Comment: *A system that is based on reputation points...*: rep points don't confer any real power and answers are deemed "correct" based on community opinion, not the pre-existing rep of the answerer. *voters are encouraged to downvote on the basis of style rather than substance.*: No one encourages that, at all. The point is that if the poor style obscures the true message of the answer and makes what is written is hard to understand, then one shouldn't be surprised at a poor response in terms of net upvotes. This is no different than poor writing in a paper or a textbook.

Comment: *I am not sure the the benefits outweigh the negatives*: any perceived negatives probably arise from expecting the site to be something it's not. Taken for what it is - an informal Q&A site contributed to by volunteers - the site is quite good at helping a lot of people and providing helpful answers. From someone who uses the site and answers questions at a record breaking rate that far surpasses any of his predecessors, it's surprising to hear that you honestly think the site could possibly be a net loss for the statistical community.

Comment: A [link](http://magazine.amstat.org/blog/2011/12/01/qasitedec11/) to the article mentioned by @RobHyndman (Interesting info!).

Comment: @Macro I think you are misinterpreting my point.  You don't have to defend the site.  I am addressing an issue that has to do with whether or not more professional statisticians should get involved with StackExchange in order to spread good statistical methodology to the widespread practice of data analysis.  Wikipedia is a great source of information.  I cite it her a lot as do many others.  But my son's high school teachers warned them not to rely on wikipedia in their school papers.  I think this is right.

Comment: @Michael I think you are misinterpreting my point. I wasn't defending the site. My first comment was pointing out two things you said that I think are mischaracterizations of the site. The second comment was expressing confusion with your attitude, which does not seem to match that of someone who has become ubiquitous on the site, as you have.

Comment: The sources can be excellent but there is no "Goodhousekeeping seal of approval" to rely on.  So experts are needed  to vouch for the veracity of an article in Wikipedia just like with a post here.  Who are the experts here?  The ones with high rep points?  I don't know much about you and many others with high reps who post answers regularly.  I know you have a PhD in statistics from Michigan only because you told me in conversation.  Otherwise you are a mystery to me.  This site is useful.  To meet a higher purposes the judges of answers should be certified experts.

Comment: ASA or RSS accreditation is a way to do it.  But would StackExchange CV change to do it?  Probably not and I am not asking it to. But for ASA to endorse and actively encourage its members to participate I think that would be necessary.

Comment: Michael, I don't know what these "higher purposes" you refer to are but, as I said before, I suspect you're expecting the site to be something it isn't. It's not a peer-reviewed publication and it's not a PhDs-only (or consultants-only) club. People should judge the answers for what they are, using critical thought and possible additional research after receiving an answer, not based on whether someone with various titles and letters after their name "certified" them to be correct. **Giant +1** to @Procrastinator's comment above.

Comment: Let me say it load and clear. MY COMMENTS ARE NOT ADDRESSING THE SITE OR WHAT IT SHOULD BE.  THE SITE IS FINE FOR ITS PURPOSE.  My point is that I see a system where expert statisticans answer questions given by othe statisticians and data users can be a vehicle for helping to spread improved statistical practice.  Stackexchange cannot do that for the reasons I have mentioned.

Comment: If individuals want to mention the site to colleague and encourage them to use it that is fine.  I was think more in terms of getting a significant professional society presense. That would for an objective of improving statistical practice.  I think the ASA could make something like the question /answer format available where responses could be trust.  ASA accreditation might be one way.  There could be others.  but the expertise of the individuals answering the question must be known so that the answer can be consistently trusted. Stackexchange wouldn't do that.

Comment: The statement "I am addressing an issue that has to do with whether or not more professional statisticians should get involved with StackExchange in order to spread good statistical methodology to the widespread practice of data analysis" seems contradictory to "MY COMMENTS ARE NOT ADDRESSING THE SITE OR WHAT IT SHOULD BE".

Comment: @Michael, As a moderator I'm investigating one of your more worrisome claims: "I have seen correct answers that are counter to the OPs faulty intuition be downvoted and incorrect answers be upvoted because they agree with faulty intuition." Could you please provide links to a few examples so I can ascertain the extent of the problem and consider what might be done to improve things? Also, I'm unsure how to address the charge of "no real quality control or consistency," because that goes directly to the activities of the community and its mods. Could you share some of the supporting evidence?

Comment: @whuber I appreciate your taking my comments seriously and your strong interest in improving the site.  People are misinterpreting and getting defensive.  You asked me to encourage ASA members to join the site to help improve the quality of questions and answers.  During the jSM I have listened to the Presidential Address and other invited lectures. Improving statistical practice is important to me and is a goal of the ASA.  They have even started an annual conference on it.  Presidient Robert Rodiguez would be very receptive to ideas that can have an impact on improving statistical practice.

Comment: I would like to make the case that StackExchange CV is doing that.  But I am not sure that it is.  I think an ASA site similar to StackExchange CV could do that.  I discuss StackExchange with a colleague here and we agreed that there are features here that we probably cannot change like use of pseudonames.  We cannot clearly identify the authorities from the novices. Hence the problems I raise.  But I would not criticize Wikipedia and I would not criticize StackExchange.  They both serve good purposes.

Comment: @Michael In thinking this over I saw merit in many of your points, but I'm not sure your somewhat negative prognosis is entirely warranted. As cases in point, check out the MathOverflow site (an SE-like forum for professional mathematicians) and SE's own theoretical computer science site (which addresses only research-level questions). I am not suggesting that SE or ASA set up a research stats site--that would miss the point of addressing practical questions--but seeing the good work done elsewhere might make you more sanguine about what we can achieve with the SE model.

Comment: I will write to  Dr. Rodriguez and suggest that he go to the website and see the kinds of questions and answers that appear here.  The quality of most questions and most answers is high and I think he could see the value here.  I may even submit my own column on it and how this type vehicle can be used to improve statistical practice.  But to achieve that goal I would want to know upfront the credentials of the moderators and those answering questions.

Comment: I cite wikipedia quite often because I only site statistical articles that I can judge the content on.  High school children are prohibited from doing that in their essays and research papers.  That is right because you should not site something implying accuracy to it when you don't know its correctness.  We do not know the authors of the articles and anyone can freely modify them.  Moderators and high rep members can edit and modify answers on CV also and if the source uses a pseudonym and provides no serious biography you can't be assured of credibility.

Comment: @whuber The case that really bothered me lately was the question on Bayes methods generalizing frequentist methods.  The first answer was a yes.  It was upvoted and checked and even got positive comment and thank you from the OP.  I decided to write an answer explaining why that answer was wrong.  Mine got downvotes.  Your comment and procrastinators rescued me.  Can we always count on the moderators coming to the rescue?  Will we always have expert moderators who are dilligent?  I don't know.  It is certainly not guaranteed by the way they are picked.

Comment: So in my mind I keep debating "Can CV improve statistical practice?" I don't think I can be confident that it always will even if it is having some positive impact now.  But it has features that I think could be very effective at doing just that.

Comment: @MattParker my comments are not contradictory.  I am not critical of the site.  I believe its goals are to help people with statistical problems and perhaps teach a little.  That it can due reasonably well inspite of what I think are difficulties.  Getting it to be a vehicle for general improvement of statistical practice is a higher goal that I would have as well as the ASA.  That is something StackExchange cannpt do without major changes.  That may be better done by other sites. I am stuggling with a different issue which is whether to encouraging other statisticians to join StackExchange.

Comment: Let's avoid some possible misconceptions, @Michael. (1) Moderators are permanent, as long as we remain active. The election process by which we are selected has tended to work well. (2) You fail to mention more prominent goals, as others have explained. Please re-read the site's "About" page. (3) The examples set within our best threads offer an extraordinary and unprecedented look at actual statistical practice. If you think there are *better* practices, then please encourage the best people you know to join us and show us how it's done. (4) Exactly what "major changes" would be needed?

Comment: As far as comparisons to Wikipedia go, I respectfully suggest you are laboring under outmoded misimpressions: the world has long [passed you by](http://arstechnica.com/uncategorized/2006/11/8296/). Now the onus is on you to establish that an openly debated freely editable platform--one of the four pillars of SE--is *not* less credible or trustworthy than an encyclopedia edited by experts. This is what has most astonished me about CV: anonymous people, laboring out of love, frequently provide *corrections to* and *better answers* than many of the recognized experts who have participated here.

Comment: @whuber I can buy that in part.  I know that Procrastinator , Macro and others who remain anonymous are able to give expert answers.  Probably they are experts not looking to get credit for their unselfish work.  But novices ask questions and they can't judge answers.  Yet they will and sometimes they make poor judgements.  My desire for credential is that they know they can trust the answer.  Moderators are often anonymous too.

Comment: All three (not two!) moderators, *on this site*, have a link to their homepage, as many users, although SE policy does not require to state private information or qualifications. But that's not really the issue here. Novices are welcome here, as are professional statisticians, because we all aim at providing users with a repository of knowledgeable and long-lasting answers to specific and well-thought questions, in the spirit of Stack Exchange community-driven sites. (...)

Comment: (Con't) I believe the issue we should focus on, and the one which was stated in your opening question, is how professional statisticians might get involved in this site, what they can expect from this site (compared to ASA listserver, for example) and what benefit they can derive for themselves and for the community.

Comment: @chl  I have access to everyones homepage too.  What I have seen is mostly anonymous people with little or no biographical information. Again that is not critical of the site. Some of the discussion may seem to be off topic.  But I am trying to explain my thinking about asking ASA to help bring in members. 0y explanation is that my pitch would have been that StackExchange CV educates and improves statistical practice.  I just find that I can't make a convincing argument because everything is based on votes by novices and "experts".

Comment: I think that the old way of simply encouraging colleagues to check it out and decide for themselves is the best approach. I do think that of ASA would create a question and answer site with the CVs approach but with experts answering and judging.  That would raise the quality of answers and if it is done right it could improve statistical education and practice. It requires the kind of popularity that CV has.

Comment: @whuber When you say the world has passed me by and that the burden is on me to show one way is better than the other is offbase and misses the point.  I can see that StackExchange CV works well usually. The problem is that novices judge and can be fooled.  Something can sound right and jive with their preconceived notion and they can easily vote for a wrong answer or downvote a correct one. The only check is the moderators.  We have three but at a given time any from 0 to 3 can be online.  Ihe analogy to wikipedia is good.  I am surprised by the quality of statistical items on wikipedia.

Comment: *The problem is that novices judge and can be fooled*: A lot of the voting on this site is done by [a rather small group of people](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters&filter=all). I've interacted with most of these people and I'd trust their votes. Novices don't vote much and so the influence of uninformed voting seems negligible - we're still patiently waiting for the apparently widespread examples of this "problem". In any case, to (roughly) quote MansT: "Reputation on the site, in the usual sense of the word, is determined the same way it is in the real world, not by upvotes".

Comment: @Macro You keep defending the site as though it is necessary to do so in response to my comments.  Why can't you see that I agree the site works well! My point is not whether or not it works well now or in the future.  I have no objection to it.  I think it has great value.  My point is that while I see it as a model for a website that could enhance statistical practice and educate non-statisticians in statistics in an informal incremental way there are no safeguards to ensure an absoulte standard.  Individual judgement decides and the moderators are the ones who provides the checks on misuse.

Comment: But the moderators are selected by the community.  Experts become experts based on votes from the community.  What guarantees that the experts will continue to be experts.  We believe they are now based on our own subjective view of their knowledge from their questions and answers.

Comment: Over the past few days my doubts about the site are growing because I am seeing too many questions closed and voted down.  Also since I started this question for discussion I have on the one hand gotten a lot of interest but on the other some resentment (misplaced in my opinion) that has led to an unsual rash of downvotes, unupvotes and unchecked votes that don't make sense.  In one case I would say Macro's uncheck of my answer was very much justified but only because his checkmark in the first place had no good justification.

Comment: I would appreciate the site much more if people would vote in a serious fashion consistently.

Comment: As someone who asks questions on this site and has gained a lot of benefit from those who are willing to take the time to respond to those questions - I think the idea of credentials and all this concern about being down voted is over blown. I can tell you that responses from those interested in listing all their publication or membership credentials are almost always the least helpful. Citing 10 scholarly journal articles has a place, but typically those that have real experience and passion for the topics they respond to - provide FANTASTIC value through well explained and crafted answers.

Comment: con't... I think asking how to recruit practitioners, good teachers and how to clone the whubers, chi, macro, procrastinator,RobHyndman and similar is the best question to ask.

Comment: @B_Miner: Thank you very much for providing your thoughtful perspective. The people *asking* the (good) questions are just as important, if not more so, to overall site health than those answering. Hopefully other "questioners" that may be lurking and reading this thread will be emboldened enough by your reply to provide their own thoughts. I hope this will occur.

Comment: B_Miner and cardinal:  My mentioning of credentials is not a critique of the site.  I think everyone is entitled to put as much or as little into their bio as they choose.  I do think that sometimes I would like to know who I am talking to.  I know Huber and even met him in person once. I can completely trust the competence of Macro, procrastinator, jbowman, chl, mbq, Peter Flom, IrishStat, whuber, cardinal and many others.  We are fortunate to have whuber, chi and mbq as moderators.

Comment: But I know this because I am a professional statistician and am in a position to be able to judge based on my own knowledge. Others who use statistics but have limited knowledge are welcome members of the community but are not always able to make good judgements.  As I mentioned before I have seen examples where they make bad judgements.  The voting system works well and most people don't abuse it.  But I have seen abuses and retaliation too. these are bad aspects of the voting system.

Comment: When I comment on a different system it is only in the context of a way to construct an online vehicle in a question and answer format that will educate users on the statistics that is essential to their work and generally promote good statistical practice.  CV may be accomplishing that.  I am not sure.  But without assurance that our monitors and experts arer truly experts it is what my colleague described it "a shell game".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the opposite to Michael in one respect: it's important that *no* assurance should be given that the accepted answers are sound.

Many of the questions on CV concern real-life problems. A site for learners of Statistics to help each other learn is unequivocally a boon to the discipline; a site where professionally certified statisticians purport to provide solutions to non-statisticians on the basis of reading a couple of paragraphs about their problem would be a travesty of the consulting process. As it stands the onus is on askers of questions to make them clear & include all relevant information, & to critically evaluate the answers; anything that tended to give a contrary impression should be, & probably would be, of concern to professional bodies or learned societies considering lending their support to CV.

Statistical societies worldwide impose obligations on their members to keep on learning, help others learn, &  promote public understanding of the discipline: CV is already well suited to help them fulfil these obligations.

Comment: Agreed. I'd also underline a widespread comment on the original post that orienting discussion to one national association (for all its international links and roles) and to the situation in one country is quite inappropriate, if not insensitive. CV is an international forum.

Comment: @Nick: Absolutely. In fact quite a lot of things in this question & the comments perhaps side-tracked responses from the main issue, which is quite a worthwhile one to think about.

Comment: And I wasn't thinking about approaching presidents to get some sort of seal of approval, but sending in an article for the newsletter, suggesting a link to CV in the website, stuff like that.

Comment: @Horst: Assuming that opening sentence is followed by a statement of the goals of the analysis & the particular difficulty encountered - otherwise it would just get closed - I don't see any general grounds for concern. Many of us - again, at all levels of statistical experience & education - learn new stuff through first bumping up against issues that arise when trying to analyse a particular data-set. Where the OP is obviously out of his depth people often *do* suggest consulting a statistician or reading up on the subject.

Answer (score 25):

As we are close to exhausting the comment thread, I will add my voice
here. This is a personal take as a two-year member on this site.

I thought the original idea was to do some brainstorming on how to bring the
attention of ASA members, and probably statisticians from other societies,
to this site, Cross Validated.

> The great thing that CV does is to get the experts to teach the novices some
>   basic statistics in the context of problems they are working on.

Yes, it is true that we see a lot of good answers from working statisticians
or consultants to working problems, but there are also many interesting
exchanges between experts themselves. I don't think 'teaching novices' may
really motivate professional statisticians to visit this site. Instead we
need to clearly define what they can expect from this site (compared to ASA
listserver, for example) and what benefit they can derive for themselves and
for the community. In my view, an open platform for exchanges like this is an
unique opportunity to give his voice to anyone interested in statistics, and
share his opinion with others, whatever their level of expertise. It is
close to the idea of [Open
Science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_science), and in any case it
offers new perspectives for experts and casual users to become acquainted
with specific problems and engage in fruitful discussions. Who are the experts
on this site? Everyone that provided the right answer to a nice question is
a candidate. Everyone who consistently provides good answers to specific
questions associated to a specific tag is certainly an expert, and he is
probably perceived as such by the community. Other professional
statisticians might enjoy exchanging with him.

**We are a community of benevolent users.** The purpose of this site, and
more generally any sites in the Stack Exchange network, is to provide users
with a repository of knowledgeable and long-lasting answers to specific and
well-thought questions. Nothing more. We do not ask users who they are: they
are free to add some personal information in their public profile. We do not
ask users to be online everyday, but we expect they will be kind enough to
follow questions and answers in which they are involved, and contribute to
the community by voting, flagging, and helping the community as a whole (and
writing blog posts if they have some free time :-). People involved in QAs
get reputation and badges, as recognition of their participation. With
higher reputation comes higher power to boost this site. No rating system is
perfect, but the one which was chosen is generally doing its job: good
answers get higher votes, active members get higher reputation. This
reflects the opinion of the community, which is composed of experts and
students in applied and theoretical statistics, casual users of statistics
or "anyone else doing data analysis or interested in it as a discipline."

**We ask questions and propose answers.** New users can [vote
up](https://stats.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) when they have 15
rep. Starting with 125 rep, they can [vote
down](https://stats.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-down). They are always
free to accept an answer: this is their very own decision to mark an answer
as useful with respect to the question they asked. Finally, askers can
always change their mind if a new and better answer is offered. Again, this
decision is that of the user. When the OP vote up and accept an answer, that
makes up a total of 25 points to the respondent. Other users can cast their
votes, in either direction, which offers an obvious counterbalance to this
individual decision. Most importantly, votes help to sort out good
questions and promote good answers.

**We need votes.** [Voting is one of the bases of this
site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/). However,
as has been said on
[tex.SE](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2012/04/voting-up-voting-down/),
"content should always be the key." Everybody on this site can participate,
and with growing reputation users get more privileges (retagging, voting to
close, voting to reopen, wiki edits, etc.) to help to maintain this site in
good health. 
Earning reputation in recognition of exemplary participation on SE has no
other goal than allowing users to weigh in site management and expression of
the user community. In the end, they become *trusted users*, and, certainly,
they have always been willing to share their knowledge and expertise.

**We elect moderators.** Moderators are not elected to dictate anything on
SE sites, but to help the community of users with specific tasks, in
particular they "look at every flagged post, and take action if necessary,"
as described in [A Theory of
Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).
As high-rep users often do, they also remind users with SE policy, provide
guidelines for a better interaction on this wiki. It is important to
remember that they are part of the community.

**This site is really a good opportunity for us.** I believe everyone here would agree that we try our best to promote best
practices in statistical data analysis by providing authoritative and
meticulous answers. Users do their best, taking into account
the purpose of this site. Moreover, the SE system offers great facilities
for live edits, updates, and add support for rich formatting of text. This
is something that is clearly impossible on listserver. Professional
statisticians might see this as a great opportunity to have more interactive and perennial exchanges.

> To meet a higher purposes the judges of answers should be certified
>   experts.

Who will decide on that? Does that mean that we have to exhibit a blue/white
card attesting our level of knowledge, thereby allowing a weighted voting
process? I think this reflects a misunderstanding of the purpose of Stack
Exchange sites. "Professional statisticians" can decide to participate or
not, as they do when interacting on dedicated mailing-lists, maintaining
software, or providing up to date material on their own websites. We won't
ask them what's their level of expertise is; we just ask them to provide the
best possible answer, in the spirit of Stack Exchange community-driven
sites.

I am sympathetic with any suggestion to extend this network of professional
statisticians and people interested in statistics as a discipline. Surely,
everybody will be happy with accredited statisticians visiting our site from
time to time, but to challenge the actual quality of this site, as the
following comment of yours might suggest

> the system needs structure and consistency it seems to me to lack. A system
>   that is based on reputation points assigned inconsistently by members who
>   are novices and have no expertise to judge the correctness or incorrectness
>   of answers.

runs counter to the motivations of Stack Exchange sites where everyone can
contribute. Interested professionals are invited to participate, to the
extent of their availability and their own interest.

To sum up,

> CrossValidated is for statisticians, data miners, and anyone else doing data
>   analysis or interested in it as a discipline.

- Anyone interested in contributing to this site is welcome.
- Contributions made by professional statisticians are greatly appreciated.
- This site promotes well-crafted and useful answers to specific problems,
  and it is driven by a community of benevolent users who all aspire to high
  quality.

Comment: (+1) This is a fantastically well-composed, thoughtful answer. Thank you for taking what must have been a nontrivial amount of time out of your schedule to write such a nice answer!

Comment: Very nice.  I just want to emphasize a point that you touched upon.  Credentials shouldn't matter; good content matters.  An answer by "John Smith, Ph.D." shouldn't be given more weight than a better answer by "BaseballGuy42" who posts anonymously and may or may not have the same credentials.  Good content should be able to speak for itself without merely appealing to authority.  To the extent the other stuff matters, it's to better inform your Bayesian prior estimate of the quality of the content :)

Comment: @chl +1 and Thanks chl: I think this is a very good argument for what the site stands for and why professional society members such as the ASA membership might want to join. Could you turn this into an invitation letter that any of us could use to invite colleagues?

Comment: On the certification issue you and others continue to take my comment out of context. I think that if there is to be a site not necessarily StackExchange that can be trusted as a source for novices to go to to have their questions answered confidence can only be obtained if there is some form of certification. Certification is not a big problem. The ASA has it, Statistical Society of Canada has it, and the Royal Statistical Society has it. I happen to have ASA PSTAT certification so I know how it works. ASA has a committee that reviews applications.

Comment: Applications include CVs and three recommendations. There is a serivce fee to the ASA for processing certification and certified members remain certified for five years and can be renewed at these 5 year intervals. The judgement is based on experience and competency.  No specific level of education is required.  You do not have to have a masters degree or a PhD to be a certified professional statistician but you do need to satisfy the committee that you are competent and sufficiently trained.

Comment: StackExchange will not make such changes and therefore I think as good as it may be it will attract some but others may be reluctant to participate. I am proposing that the ASA may want to move further to meet general goals it has that such a forum could produce.

Comment: So please try to see that I am raising two separate issues.  1. Find a method to encourage ASA members and other professional statisticians to join StackExchange to continue to raise the quality of discussion and answers to questions on the CV site.  2. Try to convince ASA leadership that the question and answer approach of StackExchange could be taken up in an ASA website where the ASA could provide a similar service with the goal of improvement quantitative literacy and advancing the quality of statistic practice in society.

Comment: @MichaelC: Regarding _"...can be trusted as a source for novices to go to to have their questions answered confidence can only be obtained if there is some form of certification."_ I don't agree with this sentiment. First of all, good CV answers often contain links and references to other sources. Second, the voting system _usually_ works very well for pointing out bad answers. Third, that someone is a certified statisticians is no guarantee that they will write a correct answer. You yourself have had to edit mistakes in your answers a few times, _because the community pointed out mistakes_.

Comment: I think that the fact that errors in answers by a very experienced ASA PSTAT certified statistican who has authored several books are caught by the community is evidence that our system can be trusted to result in trustworthy answers...

Comment: @MichaelChernick I understand the two issues, and I answered the first one because this was the original question: How to encourage ASA members to join given how this system works. The second issue sounds like a call to fork a site like this on ASA servers and open it to certified users only, because you see a need to change two major 'drawbacks' of our system: user anonymity and vote reliability, that credentials from external judges are supposed to correct. This is less relevant to CV itself, IMHO, and it has to be demonstrated that this won't turn into a "shell game" between experts.

Comment: @chl I really appreciate your thoughtful answers and comments.  PSTAT certification is just one possibility for the credential.  The site itself would not be restricted to experts.  That would defeat the purpose.  But judging questions and answers should be done by experts to ensure relevance and correctness.

Comment: @MansT Everyone makes mistakes including experts and that is why many experts are needed to check and correct the answers of others. Right now I agree that the system works well.  But it is not the kind of system that I feel is guaranteed to work consistently.  I have seen individual examples where things go wrong.

Comment: Very interesting thread. As somebody who only recently came across this site I have been very impressed with the quality of the answers (and moderatorship) and the obvious commitment and enthusiasm displayed by members. I would caution that any move towards credentials etc could be a move towards exclusivity which might discourage new users. I am not formally trained in statistics but hold a PhD in a related field, does this mean that my answers are therefore always less valuable than a qualified statistician?

Answer (score 14):

My forecast is pessimistic.

The community of academic statisticians (aka ASA members) produces fantastic initiatives that would greatly enhance the discipline as a whole. Unfortunately, most of them are one-man uphill battles.

When Jim Pitman was the President of IMS, he [actively promoted](http://stat-www.berkeley.edu/users/pitman/ims_pres_address.pdf) the idea of having more publications in open access. There were many good points in his presentations and articles on this (of which the most tangilbe outcomes is posting the Annals contents in arxiv.org). An obvious one is that it is cheaper for the end user -- why should one pay the commercial publisher for essentially zero added value? We submit a properly formatted, camera-ready paper (although I've had a number of examples of publishers who retyped my LaTeX into Word... it is difficult to desribe how furious I was fixing their typoes and furmatting errars); why paying somebody $1000/year to access five papers from this journal? Another idea had to do with incentives in evaluation of faculty: OK, we all understand that you need to publish in JASA and Annals to get tenured. But once you are there, why don't give more consideration to free online journals? Let the young faculty play in these high impact journals. People know who Peter Hall or David Dunson is if they've opened more than three issues of JASA or Annals over the last five years, and you don't need to continue proving yourself anymore to get promoted any further. Make your work accessible to non-academic researchers and the third world. Wonderful ideas; how much of that has changed over the past five years? None.

David Banks visited what then was my department of statistics, and gave a talk that analyzed whether [Wikipedia is complete](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9780470315262.ch5/summary), in the sense of having every topic covered. In the end of the presentation, he urged the members of the audience to contribute to wikipedia and help improving it. Wonderful ideas; how many statisticians have contributed to Wikipedia over the past five years? A handful, I guess; and we probably have all of them on this site of benevolent statisticians, as chl put it. (I do list my contributions in my curriculum vitae, just in case I were to run across another benevolent statistician at the evaluating end.)

Finally, just looking at our website, of the big names in statistics (defined as people who would get an immediate recognition from about half of the attendees at the JSM... or whatever the analogue is in Europe -- sorry, my view is totally obstructed by the US borders), we have Michael Chernick and Frank Harrell, who does not seem to be very active recently. That's a very low hit rate -- I guess I could put another hundred or so names into this hat of the authors of the important books and papers who would fit the above definition.

Of the existing statistics cultures, only consulting (represented wonderfully by whuber) may have any incentives to contribute actively to CV. Academic statisticians need to publish their papers in as highly ranked journals as possible, and CV does not have an impact factor. Industry statisticians need to report their hours, and CV is not a paying client. Consultants may seek to extend their business, so CV may indeed be an engine. Once the criteria for promotion IN ALL DEPARTMENTS would include maintaing a 1000 rep/year on CV and maintaining at least three wikipedia pages in your expertise area, making at least one edit a year in each of them, the situation will change, and we'll all be crowded out by people who are better statisticians than StasK is. (I've heard of people who made contributing to CV a requirement for their consulting classes, though.)

Here's a little bit of the silver lining. The faculty search committees would benefit from CV in the parts of evaluating the communication abilities of their candidates: if a person can explain things well on CV to statistically un- (or under-) prepared audience, chances are they will succeed in the classroom or in the consulting function, too. This is the only realistic selling point I see as a way of explaining how CV can be useful to the statistical community, the way it exists and functions right now. If young faculty were to work on CV and to bring this kind of culture into their classes, we might see the paradigm shift in the nexts twenty or so years.

Comment: I agree that even with good intentions to help academic statisticians may find that they have very little time to contribute to a site like CV.  But I have notice large participation of statisticians ( mostly industrial consulting statisticians) on the ASA eGroups. It was on the consulting statisticians eGroup that I learned about CV from Bill Huber. I think there can be some gain here.  My idea of aN ASA site to do something like this may be a pipe dream but the goal of improving quantitative literacy and statistical practice is are clear goals consistently raised by ASA presidents.

Comment: Michael, you are right, ASA groups and section mailing lists are quite active, although among these, the Section on Consulting is by far the most active -- again, see the reasons I outlined above. Other groups and sections may have lower activity levels; SRMS, the second or the third largest sections, has its own mailing list outside amstat.org, and it's kinda active with ~5-10 messages a week.